# Don't execute function on specific posts

Tags: exclude

```
function content_strip_img($content) {
global $post;
if ($post->ID !== 1 || $post->ID !== 2 || $post->ID !== 3 ) {   
    return preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', $content);
    }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'content_strip_img');
```

That doesn't seem to work? How do I exclude specific posts from a function - i.e. execute the function on all **other** posts?

Comment: This seems like a right idea, at which point in page load are you trying to execute the function? If you dump `$post` does it contain expected data?

Comment: Updated is the whole function that I'm using inside functions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a logic problem primarily, but your filter is faulty as well.

Think carefully about that conditional. If any one of those values-- `$post->ID !== N`-- is `true`, the whole thing is true, and as a post can only have one ID for any post two of those conditions will be true. It won't work the way you want. What you need is `&&`. It sounds strange, but think it through. The only way that can true is if the post ID is none of those values.

Secondly, you should always (nearly always) `return` content from `the_content`. If you don't you effectly remove the post content.

I have rewritten this code for you:

```
function content_strip_img($content) {
  global $post;
  if ($post->ID !== 1 && $post->ID !== 2 && $post->ID !== 3 ) {   
    $content = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', $content);
    $content = 'Test';
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'content_strip_img');
```